In Apple Oauth, Id_token that redirect response is not include user info

I configured the login URL as follows:
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_type=code%20id_token
&state=state
&scope=name%20email
&response_mode=form_post

According to the Apple documentation, the response to these requests should include the state, code, id_token, and user fields.
However, in my case, the user field is not returned and the id_token does not include user information.
Here is my code:
@RestController
public class CallBackController {

    private final CreateSecret secret;

    public CallBackController(CreateSecret secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/callback")
    public ResponseEntity<Info> test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) throws Exception {
        var res = secret.login(params.get("code"));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

@Service
public class CreateSecret {

    @Value("${apple.team-id}")
    private String APPLE_TEAM_ID;

    @Value("${apple.login-key}")
    private String APPLE_LOGIN_KEY;

    @Getter
    @Value("${apple.client-id}")
    private String APPLE_CLIENT_ID;

    @Value("${apple.redirect-url}")
    private String APPLE_REDIRECT_URL;

    @Value("${apple.key-path}")
    private String APPLE_KEY_PATH;

    private final static String APPLE_AUTH_URL = "https://appleid.apple.com";

    public Info login(String code) throws Exception {
        String userId;
        String email;
        String accessToken;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(generateAuthToken(code));

        System.out.println(jsonObj.toJSONString());
        SignedJWT signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse((String) jsonObj.get("id_token"));

        JWTClaimsSet getPayload = signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet();

        JSONObject payload = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(JSONValue.toJSONString(getPayload.toJSONObject()));

        System.out.println(payload.toJSONString()); // Result that printed not include info
        return Info.of("userId", "email"); // Temporary
    }

    public String generateAuthToken(String code) throws IOException {
        if (code == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed get authorization code");

        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        params.add("client_id", APPLE_CLIENT_ID);
        params.add("client_secret", createClientSecretKey());
        params.add("code", code);
        params.add("redirect_uri", APPLE_REDIRECT_URL);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, headers);

        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    APPLE_AUTH_URL + "/auth/token",
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    httpEntity,
                    String.class
            );

            return response.getBody();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Apple Auth Token Error");
        }
    }

    public String createClientSecretKey() throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> headerParamsMap = new HashMap<>();
        headerParamsMap.put("kid", APPLE_LOGIN_KEY);
        headerParamsMap.put("alg", "ES256");

        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setHeaderParams(headerParamsMap)
                .setIssuer(APPLE_TEAM_ID)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 30))
                .setAudience(APPLE_AUTH_URL)
                .setSubject(APPLE_CLIENT_ID)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, getPrivateKey())
                .compact();
    }

    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(APPLE_KEY_PATH);
        String privateKey = new String(resource.getInputStream().readAllBytes());

        Reader pemReader = new StringReader(privateKey);
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(pemReader);
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
        PrivateKeyInfo object = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();

        return converter.getPrivateKey(object);
    }
}

I tried changing the login URL and editing my application code, but the id_token still does not include user information and the JSON response does not include the user field.
Any help would be appreciated.
